# How to calculate consecutive missed visit in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

I want to find consecutive missed visit by the site. First I created a flag if visit completion = missed then 1 else 0
Next, I created the following calculation to count the consecutive
[image]

Now my questions are following,
1)  If I am counting consecutive missed visits, then shouldn’t I ignore the first index/occurrence? i.e., in this case, the count should show 8? How to do that?
2)  How to aggregate it up to site level?

Looking forward to your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read the section in the help for Table calculations, about partitioning and addressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part 1 of your question, to set the first occurence as 0, you can tweak your existing calculation: (picking up from the middle of your formula...)

```
...THEN IF FIRST()=0 THEN 0 ELSE PREVIOUS_VALUE(0)+1 END...
```

Part 2, to aggregate to site level, is more tricky. You'll need the VisitNo on Detail as it's needed for the calculation. You may need to wrap the entire calculation in:

```
IF LAST()=0 THEN [FormulaCalcField] END
```

Hence only keeping the final result of the calc. These things are complicated...

Comment: Thank you Andy, I will definitely try this approach and update here. Learning a new thing. Yes, the site level aggregation is very tricky I am out of my wit. However, my confusion is what is the right logic while counting consecutive? should we calculate all the instances or (all instances-1)